# C# DependencyService in Xamarin.Forms portable class

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I would like to use `DependencyService` using `Xamarin.Forms` in a `Portable Class Library`. In this case, the PCL is my business logic, and thus, I don't have access to nor want to install `Xamarin.Forms` in this project.

What I'm trying to do in my business logic is:

```
_login = DependencyService.Get<ILogin>();
```

I am using `SimpleContainer` for registration of my services.

My question is thus, which `Service Locator` can I use in my business logic project?

Comment: Which MVVM framework are you using? `Caliburn.Micro`? Also, are you using `Xamarin.Forms`?

Comment: I am using Xamarin.Forms

Comment: DependencyService is XF's DI mechanism.  It is part of the XF nuget package.  You do not mix it with another DI container like SimpleContainer. See https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/

Comment: Problem is that in Portable class I don't have access to XF. Which Dependency Injection Container can I then use here?

Comment: Where is your interface implemented? On your `iOS` and `Android` projects?

Comment: Inplementation is also in another pcl which is included in ios and android project

Comment: http://arteksoftware.com/ioc-containers-with-xamarin/

Comment: Could you post some code to how and where `Login` is implemented? As your post is currently written, it's kind of difficult to understand what you're trying to achieve, which is why you're getting so many different questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want to install `Xamarin.Forms` in your `PCL` you can still program against your platform-specific implementations in your `PCL`.

Normally, like you mentioned, you could access the platform-specific class instance in your `PCL` project using something like:-

```
_login = DependencyService.Get<ILogin>();
```

However this creates a dependency on `Xamarin.Forms`.

To get around this you can implement your interface `ILogin` in the `PCL`.

You will then create a static class with either one of the following, depending if it is a global reference (with only one instance ever existing), or whether you want a new instance of your platform-specific class implementation instantiated for use within the `PCL` project:-

**Option 1 : Create a single, global instance, that every call in your `PCL` goes through**

To do this, add the following to your `PCL`:-

```
public static MyGlobal
{
    public static ILogin MyLoginGlobalInstance;
}
```

Then in your initialization of your platform-specific **iOS** and **Android** projects you can set this global property in your `PCL` matching a new instance created in each of the platform-specific projects, such as:-

```
MyPCLProject.MyGlobal.MyLoginGlobalInstance = new Login();
```

By creating it **on the local platform-specific project**, and setting this in the `PCL`, you can then access the instance within the `PCL` according to your interface as you have defined in `ILogin` along the lines of:-

```
MyPCLProject.MyGlobal.MyLoginGlobalInstance.{some interface member}
```

**Option 2 : Create a new instance of your platform-specific class instance, every time in your `PCL`.**

If however, you want to create a new instance of your platform-specific class everytime you need it, in your `PCL`, you can do the following.

In your `PCL` create the following:-

```
public static MyGlobal
{
    public static Func<ILogin> CreateNewInstance_Login;
}
```

Then, in your **platform-specific project** you can initialize this function with something along the lines of:-

```
MyPCLProject.MyGlobal.CreateNewInstance_Login = new Func<ILogin>(()=>
{
    return new Login();
}
```

Then to consume and create **a new instance** each time within your `PCL` you create a new instance by calling:-

```
ILogin objMyLoginInstance = MyPCLProject.MyGlobal.CreateNewInstance_Login();

objMyLoginInstance.{some interface member}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear what you're trying to achieve exactly, but I take that, because of your choices in project design, the assembly implementing the services does not depend on `Xamarin.Forms` and thus you can't register them, from within the assembly, with the `[Dependency]` attribute.

As an alternative, you can register services in the DependencyService using `DependencyService.Register<T> ();`. Once the service is register, you can access it with a call to `DependencyService.Get<T> ();`

Depending on your solution architecture, it might help you or not.